# Can I put 6” recessed cans into 7” holes?

Tags: lighting

I want to replace these 7” speaker holes with recessed lighting. Are there any issues with using 6” cans and have a 0,5” border opening? I’ll be using the new-construction cans to nail to the wood instead of the remodel version so anchoring isn’t a problem. Also will be using 8” trims. Would dust from the attic be a problem? Or something else an issue?

Comment: Have you found trim rings that will cover the gap?

Comment: Hi yes, there are trip rings that are 8" wide, so the gap will be covered.

Answer (score 1):

No problem at all doing this. But I would come up with a way to fill in that gap you have. It will allow drafts and dust penetration. Personally, I'd square the opening in the ceiling, take a new piece of drywall the same size as the hole and put the hole for recessed can in it and then secure it to the existing ceiling drywall (used 1/8" plywood for securing the screws into), mud, texture, put the can in (new or old work), paint and then the trim.

Comment: I agree, but I'd endeavor to seal the gap without doing the drywall work. There are  plenty of options.

Comment: I have no dry wall experience lol. i'm thinking maybe buying very thin square ply wood and cutting a 6" hole and basically put it in between the can and opening.

Comment: That was my thought exactly. You'd probably have to split the plywood after cutting the hold so you can fit it through the drywall. I'm not sure what your insulation situation is, but you'll need to move that out of the way and use some construction adhesive or silicone to bond the plywood.